# How to use the Youtube Data API to Get a List of Shorts

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

It seems like the Youtube V3 Data Api does support Youtube Shorts. I can get information about a short via

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

This endpoint requires a list of IDs. How do I get that list of IDs without scraping youtube.com/user/shorts for the shorts themselves?

Is there a mechanism to get that list of short ids somewhere?

The typical mechanism of using the playlistItems would not work in this situation, since the relatedPlaylists object only shows an uploads Playlist. Also pulling the list of all Youtube Playlists for a channel typically includes a "#Shorts" playlist, but these seems to be shorts that were re-uploaded and have a separate ID than their shorts counterpart.

"relatedPlaylists": {
"likes": "",
"uploads": "UUOpuMFmU3RyTeXejHWldXkA"
}

I would appreciate any help / assistance in this matter :)

Comment: Your search is aimed to obtain per-user list of shorts?

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: Why not inspect contentDetails? Ex:  
`contentDetails:
     { duration: 'PT1H28M48S',
       dimension: '2d',
       definition: 'hd',
       caption: 'false',
       licensedContent: true,
       projection: 'rectangular' } } ]`

Comment: Of course searching in that particular `channelId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube Data API v3 supports videos not shorts. Just search `short` on [the API revision history](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history) to convince you so.

So you are obliged to web-scrape https://www.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID/shorts

I recommend you to try out my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/9c3c5bb1bfcd269339efd4b08217aff222e08184/channels.php#L100-L179) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/channels?part=shorts&id=CHANNEL_ID, you will get the channel shorts you are looking for in `item["shorts"]`.

For instance for [the YouTube channel `UC07-dOwgza1IguKA86jqxNA`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC07-dOwgza1IguKA86jqxNA) you would obtain:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "UC07-dOwgza1IguKA86jqxNA",
            "shorts": [
                {
                    "videoId": "9YU8vMP7Zn4",
                    "title": "Ending the COVID-19 public health emergency",
                    "thumbnails": [
                        {
                            "url": "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/9YU8vMP7Zn4\/hq720_2.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCNAFENAFSFryq4qpAwoIARUAAIhC0AEB&rs=AOn4CLD1q_FT1fksxcdxskDiA9PpR9GkAg",
                            "width": 720,
                            "height": 720
                        }
                    ],
                    "viewCount": 6600,
                    "frame0Thumbnails": [
                        {
                            "url": "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/9YU8vMP7Zn4\/frame0.jpg",
                            "width": 1080,
                            "height": 1080
                        }
                    ],
                    "timestamp": "6 days ago",
                    "channelHandle": "who",
                    "channelId": "UC07-dOwgza1IguKA86jqxNA",
                    "channelTitle": "World Health Organization (WHO)",
                    "channelThumbnails": [
                        {
                            "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/c1FW9KnEPqDdWqNw5RR9geZwt479yXfSaBXJkPgII93jOfJBaMDQTZ5nJ1fU9N4qJD2t08qlhw=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
                            "width": 48,
                            "height": 48
                        },
                        {
                            "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/c1FW9KnEPqDdWqNw5RR9geZwt479yXfSaBXJkPgII93jOfJBaMDQTZ5nJ1fU9N4qJD2t08qlhw=s88-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
                            "width": 88,
                            "height": 88
                        },
                        {
                            "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/c1FW9KnEPqDdWqNw5RR9geZwt479yXfSaBXJkPgII93jOfJBaMDQTZ5nJ1fU9N4qJD2t08qlhw=s176-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
                            "width": 176,
                            "height": 176
                        }
                    ],
                    "duration": "42 seconds"
                },
                ...
            ],
            "nextPageToken": "4qmFsgLvARIYVUMwNy1kT3dnemExSWd1S0E4NmpxeE5BGtIBOGdhWEFScVVBVktSQVFxTUFRcGtRME00VVVGU2IycHZaMWxuUTJob1ZsRjZRVE5NVjFKUVpESmtObGxVUmtwYU0xWk1VVlJuTW1GdVJqUlVhMFZSUVZKdlEwTkJRV2xGVVc5UVRWUnZlRTVxWTNwT1ZGa3pUbnBOTWsxcVZYbExaekJMUXpFNVFsZEdWbEZsVlRGQ1lUSnNXaElrTmpOalkyTXlZV010TURBd01DMHlNRFE1TFdGa1lqSXRaRFJtTlRRM1pqRXlaREpqR0FFJTNE,CgtKaWljWUJ5YXNrTSj4u4KeBg=="
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that there is [a pagination mechanism à la YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination).