# Is there a filter to get result of only shorts from YouTube data API v3?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am calling YouTube data API to get search results. I am unable to find whether the videos are shorts video or not.
I only need shorts videos result to appear when I search using channel ID

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74758155) answers your problem, right?