# How to get only short videos in YouTube api3? Desirable Android, Kotlin

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm making an Android application and connecting YouTube API there and I need to get sort videos that I get.
For example: only long, normal videos and only short videos. I'm new to YouTube API, and I don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help?

There is small part of my code:

RetroInstance file code:

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

object RetroInstance {

    fun retroInstance(): YoutubeService {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(YoutubeService::class.java)
    }
}
```

And YoutubeService code:

```
import com.example.alaproapp.model.YoutubeModel
import retrofit2.*
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface YoutubeService {

    @GET("search")
    fun getAllData(
        @Query("key") key: String = "key",
        @Query("channelId") channelId: String = "UCHVY_-jY-FayjszyX1nlGtQ",
        @Query("order") order: String = "date",
        @Query("maxResults") maxResult: String = "1800",
        @Query("part") part: String = "snippet,id"
    ): Call<YoutubeModel>
}
```

I tried to use [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/dimensions?hl=ru#Playback_Detail_Dimensions), but how I mentioned earlier I'm new to this, and I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: you don't the API predates shorts and has not been updated

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74758155) solve your problem?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison I already read this answer before to ask this question, i want to use another api's, when i tried know to use your's api it give's me error to many request, while i make only one

Comment: The error message mentions that *[hosting your own instance of the API](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/0f0f970ccc2bfc4728049f2af42c320473b89b76/README.md#install-your-own-instance-of-the-api) solves the problem*.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison I don't have any website, and want to use terminal to do something. Is there any easier way to do that?

Comment: You can host a local website from your terminal. I'm not aware of any easier alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There is another one param you should add to the /search request to filter videos by short, medium or long.

```
@Query("videoDuration") part: String = ""  // Value: long, medium, short, any
```

long - 20+ min

medium - 4-20 min

short - <= 4 min

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?
part=snippet,id
&channelId=UCHVY_-jY-FayjszyX1nlGtQ
&maxResults=1800
&order=date
&type=video
&videoDuration=long
&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

Documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Additionally, you could check the video duration. Request

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?
part=contentDetails
&id={video1 id here}
&id={video2 id here}
&id={videoN id here}
&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

In the response, find duration: PT59S = 59 sec

```
   "contentDetails": {
        "duration": "PT59S",
        "dimension": "2d",
        "definition": "hd",
        "caption": "false",
        "licensedContent": true,
        "contentRating": {},
        "projection": "rectangular"
      }
```

Documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Comment: I think OP is looking for [*shorts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube_Shorts) not *short videos*.

Comment: It will help, however it will too give me full screen videos with 1 minute duration

Comment: in the case of filtering Shorts (15-60 sec), the solution is a bit more tricky. Let's wait for the author what he says

Comment: As a workaround, you could additionally check whether the video is Shorts or not. This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/72197652/12205091

Comment: Updated the answer. Added a way to check video duration using YT API