# How to filter out shorts from a response of youtube videos

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to datascrape videos from a youtube channel but I don't want shorts, and I haven't seen anything in the meta data to get rid of shorts.

They are all listed as `youtube#video`, not `youtube#short` or something of the likes.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json

def details(channel_id):
    PLAYLIST_ID = 'UU' + channel_id[2:]
    API_KEY = '...'
    URL = f'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId={PLAYLIST_ID}&maxResults=50&key={API_KEY}'

    pageToken = ''

    while True:
        pageUrl = URL
        if pageToken != '':
            pageUrl += f'&pageToken={pageToken}'
        response = json.loads(requests.get(pageUrl).text)

        if 'items' in response and response['items'] is not None:
            print(response['items'])
            with open('j.json', 'w') as json_file:
                json.dump(response['items'], json_file)
            return response['items']
        else:
            break

        if 'nextPageToken' in response:
            pageToken = response['nextPageToken']
        else:
            break
```

Comment: The most effective would be [to list all shorts of this channel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74758155) and remove them of your results.

Comment: Another thing to note is that shorts can be up to 60 seconds in length. Thus you could also filter out videos that are 60 seconds or less. Although a normal video can also be less than 60 seconds, so it depends on your use case as well.